# Regular expression to remove whitespace from mysql insert statement

Tags: php, mysql, regex, csv

I am importing data from a CSV file using fgetcsv(), which yields an array for each row. I then implode() this array and use mysql_real_escape_string() to create a string for use in a mysql query.  It ends up looking like this:

`\"2342352353\",\" \",\"\"`

Some of the CSV files I am reading in have up to 200+ columns (rediculous, but true), so the insert statements become extremely long.  To make them not so lengthy, I want to get rid of any spaces or blanks in the insert statement.  So, the statement above should become:

`\"2342352353\",,`

So I am looking at 2 ways to solve this. First, I could walk through the array, and use trim() to find any entries with spaces and make them blank.  Then I could do a  str_replace() on the resulting string like so:

```
for ($x=0; $x<sizeof($data); $x++) {
    $data[$x] = trim($data[$x]) == ''  ?  ''  :  $data[$x];
}
$insert_string = '\\"' . mysql_real_escape_string(implode('","', $data)) . '\\"';
str_replace('\"\"', '', $insert_string);
```

Second approach is to skip walking through the array and just use regex to remove any occurrences of `\" \"`, but there could be any number of spaces in the middle of the delimited quotes.

My question is 1st and foremost, how do I do this using regex?  And secondly, which way would be faster?

Once I get the regex answer, I will do some benchmarking and will update with the results.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this regex?

`\\"\s*\\"`

Used in your code above:

`preg_replace('/\\\"\s*\\\"/', '', $insert_string);`

The `\s*` matches any number of whitespace characters.

And I'd eat my hat if regex was slower than iterating through your CSV file...

Comment: Well a couple of things.  For one, don't eat your hat! 

Secondly, I presume you meant `preg_replace()` rather than `str_replace()`.

Thirdly, this pattern was close, but for some reason I had to delimit the double quotes inside of the pattern: `preg_replace('/\\\"\s*\\\"/', '', $insert_string);`

This works now and I will award you the answer since you got me pretty close.  But do you know why I had to delimit the double quote?

Comment: I used `str_replace()` because that's what you used in your question. I do not know PHP fluently. I fixed my answer above.

Comment: Okay.  But do you know why the double quotes have to be delimited?

Comment: You're delimiting the `\ `, not the `"`.